# Synchronization in java - Can we set priority to a synchronized access in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Synchronization works by providing exclusive access to an object or method by putting a Synchronized keyword before a method name. What if I want to give higher  precedence to one particular access if two or more accesses to a method occurs at the same time. Can we do that?

Or just may be I'm misunderstanding the concept of Synchronization in java. Please correct me. 
I have other questions as well,

Under what requirements should we make method synchronized? 
When to make method synchronized ? And when to make block synchronized ? 
Also if we make a method synchronized will the class too be synchronized ? little confused here.

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Try this link: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/starvation-and-fairness.html#locks

Comment: Its all about shared state. Don't think of synchronized methods or classes, just about state (=fields) that can be accessed by multiple threads. If that's the case, it must be protected from concurrent access. Therefore use synchronization mechanisms, either synchronized statement or the newer mechanisms that exist since Java 5.

Comment: http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#synctr1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Sadly Java synchronization and wait/notify appear to have been copied from the very poor example of Unix, rather than almost anywhere else where there would have been priority queues instead of thundering herds. When [Per Brinch Hansen, author of monitors and Objective Pascal,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_Brinch_Hansen) saw Java, he commented 'clearly I have laboured in vain'.

Comment: Ohh..Is that a limitation of java ? Coz many times i fall into requirement to give precedence to particular access while using synchronization. But in such abstract world of java i really couldn't catch it.

Comment: It isn't there. When you call notify(), an arbitrary choice is made among the threads blocked in wait() to be woken up. If you use notifyAll() you get the thundering herd. If you want priority you have to synthesise it yourself. See e.g. the 'fairness' parameter of RentrantLock, which doesn't give you priority as such, just the longest-wait.

Comment: @TwoThe The question is about 'synchronized'. The concurrent packages don't provide priority-based synchronization either, only 'fairness'-based.

Comment: @TwoThe And I'm really not about to let you get away with turning a very specific statement about one feature of Java, the topic of the question, and one that is shared with one of the most distinguished practicioners in the field, into a generalized claim about all of Java's synchronization options. No straw-man arguments thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution for almost everything you need in multi-threading and synchronization in the concurrent package, it however requires some thinking about what you do first. The synchronized, wait and notify constructs are like the most basic tools if you have just a very basic problem to solve, but realistically most advanced programs will (/should) never use those and instead rely on the tools available in the Concurrent package.

The way you think about threads is slightly wrong. There is no such thing as a more important thread, there is only a more important task. This is why Java clearly distinguishes between Threads, Runnables and Callables.

Synchronization is a concept to prevent more than one thread from entering a specific part of code, which is - again - the most basic concept of avoiding threading issues. Those issues happen if more than one thread accesses some data, where at least one of those multiple threads is trying to modify that data. Think about an array that is read by Thread A, while it is written by Thread B at the same time. Eventually Thread B will write the cell that Thread A is just about to read. Now as the order of execution of threads is undefined, it is as well undefined whether Thread A will read the old value, the new value or something messed up in between.

A synchronized "lock" around this access is a very brute way of ensuring that this will never happen, more sophisticated tools are available in the concurrent package like the CopyOnWriteArray, that seamlessly handles the above issue by creating a copy for the writing thread, so neither Thread A nor Thread B needs to wait. Other tools are available for other solutions and problems.

If you dig a bit into the available tools you soon learn that they are highly sophisticated, and the difficulties using them is usually located with the programmer and not with the tools, because countless hours of thinking, improving and testing has been gone into those.

**Edit**: to clarify a bit why the importance is on the task even though you set it on the thread:
Imagine a street with 3 lanes that narrows to 1 lane (synchronized block) and 5 cars (threads) are arriving. Let's further assume there is one person (the car scheduler) that has to define which cars get the first row and which ones get the other rows. As there is only 1 lane, he can at best assign 1 cars to the first row and the others need to come behind. If all cars look the same, he will most likely assign the order more or less randomly, while a car already in front might stay in front more likely, just because it would be to troublesome to move those cars around.

Now lets say one car has a sign on top "President of the USA inside", so the scheduler will most likely give that car priority in his decision. But even though the sign is on the car, the reason for his decision is not the importance of the car (thread), but the importance on the people inside (task). So the sign is nothing but an information for the scheduler, that this car transports more important people. Whether or not this is true however, the scheduler can't say (at least not without inspection), so he just has to trust the sign on the car.

Now if in another scenario all 5 cars have the "President inside" sign, the scheduler doesn't have any way to decide which one goes first, and he is in the same situation again as he was with all the cars having no sign at all.

Comment: I have one task (say) Calender to maintain date/time schedule. Now I have one thread (say) `UpdateDate` thread that updates the calender date after every 24 hrs. Okay. And there are some reader threads that actually reads the updated date value. Now I want my `updateThread` to take higher precedence at time 12.00 to change the date, so that reader thread should not end up with reading an old date. Okay. So here only one task is there `Calender`(no other task in competition with it, so how will you decide task importance ?).

Comment: so isn't my updateThread is more important here than all other at time we need to update date.

Comment: You can set the priority of one thread to high and then assign that important task to this thread (trying to be exact here). This however does not guarantee an execution on time, it just guarantees that this thread will have priority over other threads with a lower priority. If there are other high-priority threads, the order of execution is undefined. It is a bit difficult to understand that even though you set the priority on the thread, you do it because of the priority of the task. A high-priority thread could as well handle a completely unimportant task, which is then bad design.

Comment: "The synchronized, wait and notify constructs [...] most advanced programs will (/should) never use those." citation needed

Comment: @KarlRichter That is common sense: synchronized blocks execution for all threads, non-blocking synchronization (as implemented in all Java Concurrent classes) will not block execution.

Comment: The Javadoc of `Condition` suggests a simple explanation which I reference in an edit.

Comment: @KarlRichter Sorry but your edit was entirely wrong. Condition is one tool that can be used as a replacement for synchronized, but you should not use synchronized nor replace it with something similar. Proper multi-threading with the concurrent package requires an entirely different software architecture.

Comment: I want to believe you and acquire your knowledge, yet I can't if you don't add a reference.

Comment: This is not the right place for Java tutorials, please use Google. You'll find Articles like [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well in case of `synchronized`, the access is random if multiple threads are waiting for the lock. But in case you need first-come first-serve basis: Then you can probably use [`ReentrantLock(fairness)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html). This is what the api says:

> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter.
>   When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the
>   longest-waiting thread.

Else if you wish to give access based on some other factor, then I guess it shouldn;t be complicated to build one. Have a class that when call's `lock` gets blocked if some other thread is executing. When called `unlock` it will unblock a thread based on whatever algorithm you wish to.

Comment: Please note that although fairness is a nice thing in real life, it might degrade overall throughput of high concurrent applications, as it does not allow a thread that is currently arriving at a lock to simply run through if other threads are already waiting.

Comment: @isnot2bad I understand, but you wish to have FIFO service then this is expected.

Comment: You're right. I just want to say that in many situations, throughput is more important than fairness. I think it is hard to argue that fairness is really required in a certain case. Many people just set this flag mechanically to true as they think fairness is a good thing, but in fact they just don't really think about it.

Comment: @isnot2bad Couldn't agree more :)

Comment: @Jatin this is exactly what I am looking for. It might sound as an oxymoron, but, distributed ordering (!) is really what I am looking for, a specific requirement. Taking a cue from your comments, do you have any prototype of such a data structure? I can work on the 'distributed' part, if at all I can get something to start with.

Comment: @sutanudalui I am sorry but I couldnt fully understand the query? Do you mean that you wish to decide ordering based on some factor?

Comment: @Jatin yes please. Ordering, based on certain factor other than the default time based fairness normally implemented in java library.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "priority" among synchronized methods/blocks or accesses to them.  If some other thread is already holding the object's monitor (i.e. if another synchronized method or `synchronized (this) {}` block is in progress and hasn't relinquished the monitor by a call to `this.wait()`), all other threads will have to wait until it's done.

There are classes in the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package that might be able to help you if used correctly, such as priority queues.  Full guidance on how to use them correctly is probably beyond the scope of this question - you should probably read [a decent tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) to start with.

Comment: `There's no such thing as "priority"?` But I think in the world of multithreading there should be a provision to make one particular thread highly prioritized to access that synchronized method/block similar to our normal operating systems process management.

Comment: @Winn If by that you mean a higher-priority call waiting on a resource should be able to access that resource as soon as it becomes available even if lower-priority calls are waiting, you've just described one application of a [priority queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).  If by that you mean a higher-priority call to a method should be able to interrupt a lower-priority call in progress, then the lower-priority call would need to regularly check if a higher-priority call is waiting and if so yield to it until the higher-priority call is done.